# How to extract html String from Dynamic url java?

Tags: java, html

How would i extract the html string from a dynamic web page in java? I using the code below and so far it only works for static web page

```
public String DynamicExtractHtmlString(String url, int timeout, boolean options)
        throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    HttpURLConnection hConn = createUrlConnection(url, timeout, options);
    hConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
    String encoding = hConn.getContentEncoding();
    InputStream is;
    if (encoding != null && encoding.equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) {
        is = new GZIPInputStream(hConn.getInputStream());
    } else if (encoding != null && encoding.equalsIgnoreCase("deflate")) {
        is = new InflaterInputStream(hConn.getInputStream(), new Inflater(true));
    } else {
        is = hConn.getInputStream();
    }

    String enc = Converter.extractEncoding(hConn.getContentType());
    String res = createConverter(urlAsString).streamToString(is, enc);
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled())
        logger.debug(res.length() + " FetchAsString:" + urlAsString);

    return res; 
}
```

Comment: If you're looking into how to parse an HMTL page, you should look into JSoup: http://jsoup.org/

Comment: what do you mean a dynamic webpage? do you mean one that is redirected? Do you have an example of one that works and one that doesn't?